# Encoding error when trying to obtain list of files from Google Drive Api v3

Tags: python, api, flask, google-drive-api, drive

I am trying to learn how to program a web app that queries Google Drive Api. My web is in python-Flask. I've gone through most details successfully but I'm stuck here:

```py
@app.route('/analyze')
def analyze():
    if 'credentials' not in session:
        return redirect('authorize')
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(session['credentials'])

drive_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    files = drive_service.files().list().execute()
```

The credentials are loaded from the session (the user goes through the authorization flow in a different page / script). On this script, we recover the session and make a call to the Google Api:

But the call `drive.files().list().execute()` fails

The error is in the API's response and is as follows:

> ValueError: {'client_id': 'heregoesclientid', 'client_secret': 'thisisclientsecret', 'refresh_token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'scopes': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'], 'token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'token_uri': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'} could not be converted to unicode

Why can't the response be converted to Unicode? Is this a bug in Google API? Is there anything I could do to solve this?

Comment: Looking at the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), I can't see anything in your posted code that would be an issue. Can you provide more of your code, specifically how you're loading credentials, and what you're doing with `files`?

Comment: @dylanj.nz I updated my question to include more code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `google-auth` package, you need to pass the values into `Credentials` individually, instead of a dict: [See here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html).

Your code may then look like:

```
    sc = session['credentials']
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        token=sc.get('token'),
        client_id=sc.get('client_id'),
        ...etc

    )
```

Hope this helps, or let me know if you're not using `google-auth`, as this will be irrelevant.